# Z-index iframe on an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is this possible? I have tried setting `z-index: 999;` on the one I want to overlap on on, but then but no luck.

basically i am trying to overlap `#cgdiv` on `#cDiv`

Style:

```
            #cgDiv {
                z-index:999;
                display: inline-block;
                height: 100%;
                vertical-align: top;
                width: 30%;
            }

            #contentGenerator, #content {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #cDiv {
                z-index:998;
                display: inline-block;
                height: 100%;
                vertical-align: top;
                width: 69.5%;
            }

            body { margin: 0}
```

Html

```
            <HTML>
            <HEAD>


            </HEAD>
            <BODY >
            <DIV id="cgDiv">
                <IFRAME id="contentGenerator" src="content.html">
                </IFRAME>
            </DIV>
            <DIV id="cDiv">
                <IFRAME id="content" src="startNSM.html">
                </IFRAME>
            </DIV>
            </BODY>
            </HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can set `position:absolute` and `top:0` to overlap them

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```

see this fiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/qvct1tnm/2/